# Add regex validator for pull request merge / squash

Tags: github, pull-request

How can we ensure users put the jira issue key in the commit title or message when merging or squashing/merging a github.com pull request?

Most of the user's in my projects use the github web ui for pull requests.  We use a `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` to ensure they provide goal, approach and details about testing and this works well.

However, we find situations where the user doesn't place the jira issue id in the commit comments which fails to bind the commit to the jira issue.  I can use a client side hook for commits but when the user squashes her feature branch, this data won't be carried into the final commit.

Does anyone know how to add a commit message validator to the github PR itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears that Github auto populates the commit title field with the text from the first git commit on the branch then any client side validator (like the one suggested by @Vonc would meet the goal

1. Configure [jira issue key validator git client side hook](https://gist.github.com/pgilad/5d7e4db725a906bd7aa7) (ideally it could operator on the first commit on the branch only)
2. When users merge or squash in *github webui* that first commit text gets copied into the commit title field on the form.

**Detecting 1st commit**

```
if [[ $(git log master..HEAD --oneline) ]]; then
    echo "Not first commit"
else
    echo "Is first commit"
fi
```

This is not 100% as users could remove the text.  This is more of a *nudge* solution where users will take the default and we make sure the default is likely to be correct

Answer (score 0):

See "[Git commit-msg hook to validate for jira issue or the word merge](https://gist.github.com/pgilad/5d7e4db725a906bd7aa7)" as an example of a client side hook, not practical because it would need to be distributed on all clients..

You would need to setup a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in order to have a listener validating the commit message at the server level.

The alternative is to register and setup a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) like the [babel one](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/879a59085b4c6bf7fae744abe758774047427a58/.github/main.workflow#L18-L23) which would validate a commit message directly at the GitHub server level (no need to setup a listener as you would in webhooks)

Comment: Ok well, the first won't really help in the web based PR merge scenario as more PRs are from feature branches where we squash and write the commit message.  So, the client side hook details will be lost.

Comment: The 2nd may not be something that github.com allows.  The 3rd looks like it holds promise.  I'll see if either of those pans out and update this question.  Thanks